# Android: my application won't run because I need to handle an unknownhostexception. when i do it crashes

Tags: android, mongodb, exception, android-emulator

Im writing an Android application that needs to access data stored in a mongodb data base. In my on create method I keep on getting an "UnknownHostException" error. I have added the internet permission to my manifest file, restarted my developing machine, and applied a try/catch. Now, the application crashes when I run it (right as the application is opened). When I used the class I wrote for the database (CrumbsDb) outside of android, it works as intended. Please help. Sorry if my question is not detailed enough, I am new to stack overflow and compsci.

```
    String name = "Crumb Not Available";
    try {
        CrumbsDb db = new CrumbsDb();
        name = db.getName("Chipotle");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    TextView crumbName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.crumb_name);
    crumbName.setText(name);
```

Here is the error log

```
01-10 13:42:37.223: I/dalvikvm(506): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean, referenced from method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>
01-10 13:42:37.223: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1544: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getRuntimeMXBean ()Ljava/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean;
01-10 13:42:37.273: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0071
01-10 13:42:37.273: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x0074-007c in Lorg/bson/types/ObjectId;.<clinit> ()V
01-10 13:42:37.373: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.373: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.373: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.373: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.373: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;)
01-10 13:42:37.373: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.383: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.383: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.383: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.383: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.383: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.383: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.383: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.393: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.393: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.393: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.393: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.393: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.403: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.403: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.403: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.403: I/dalvikvm(506): Could not find method com.mongodb.DBPortPool.getServerAddress, referenced from method com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._set
01-10 13:42:37.403: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 441: Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;.getServerAddress ()Lcom/mongodb/ServerAddress;
01-10 13:42:37.403: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002b
01-10 13:42:37.403: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.403: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.403: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.413: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.413: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x002e-0043 in Lcom/mongodb/DBTCPConnector;._set (Lcom/mongodb/ServerAddress;)Z
01-10 13:42:37.413: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.413: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.413: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.413: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.423: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.423: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.423: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.423: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.423: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;)
01-10 13:42:37.443: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.443: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.443: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.443: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.454: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.454: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.454: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.454: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.454: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.454: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.454: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.454: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.463: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.463: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.473: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.473: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.473: I/dalvikvm(506): Could not find method com.mongodb.DBPortPool.get, referenced from method com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.fetchMaxBsonObjectSize
01-10 13:42:37.473: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 438: Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;.get ()Lcom/mongodb/DBPort;
01-10 13:42:37.473: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
01-10 13:42:37.473: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x000b-0076 in Lcom/mongodb/DBTCPConnector;.fetchMaxBsonObjectSize ()I
01-10 13:42:37.473: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.473: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.473: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.483: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.483: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.483: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.483: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.483: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.493: I/dalvikvm(506): Could not find method com.mongodb.DBPortPool.getServerAddress, referenced from method com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getAddress
01-10 13:42:37.493: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 441: Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;.getServerAddress ()Lcom/mongodb/ServerAddress;
01-10 13:42:37.493: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
01-10 13:42:37.493: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x0007-0007 in Lcom/mongodb/DBTCPConnector;.getAddress ()Lcom/mongodb/ServerAddress;
01-10 13:42:37.493: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.493: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.493: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.503: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.503: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;)
01-10 13:42:37.503: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.503: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.503: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.503: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.503: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;)
01-10 13:42:37.513: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.513: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.513: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.513: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.513: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.513: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.523: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.523: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.523: I/dalvikvm(506): Could not find method com.mongodb.DBPortPool.get, referenced from method com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.testMaster
01-10 13:42:37.523: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 438: Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;.get ()Lcom/mongodb/DBPort;
01-10 13:42:37.523: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0003
01-10 13:42:37.523: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.523: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.523: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.523: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.533: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.533: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.533: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.533: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.533: I/dalvikvm(506): Could not find method com.mongodb.DBPortPool.done, referenced from method com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.testMaster
01-10 13:42:37.533: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 437: Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;.done (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
01-10 13:42:37.533: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0032
01-10 13:42:37.533: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x0006-0023 in Lcom/mongodb/DBTCPConnector;.testMaster ()V
01-10 13:42:37.533: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x0035-0035 in Lcom/mongodb/DBTCPConnector;.testMaster ()V
01-10 13:42:37.543: I/dalvikvm(506): Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer, referenced from method com.mongodb.DBPortPool$Holder.<init>
01-10 13:42:37.543: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1543: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
01-10 13:42:37.543: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0011
01-10 13:42:37.543: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0014 in Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool$Holder;.<init> (Lcom/mongodb/MongoOptions;)V
01-10 13:42:37.553: E/dalvikvm(506): Could not find class 'javax.management.ObjectName', referenced from method com.mongodb.DBPortPool$Holder.createObjectName
01-10 13:42:37.553: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 305 (Ljavax/management/ObjectName;) in Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool$Holder;
01-10 13:42:37.553: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x004e
01-10 13:42:37.553: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x0050-0053 in Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool$Holder;.createObjectName (Lcom/mongodb/ServerAddress;)Ljavax/management/ObjectName;
01-10 13:42:37.553: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.553: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.553: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.553: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.553: E/dalvikvm(506): Could not find class 'com.mongodb.DBPortPool', referenced from method com.mongodb.DBPortPool$Holder.close
01-10 13:42:37.553: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 56 (Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;) in Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool$Holder;
01-10 13:42:37.553: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0017
01-10 13:42:37.563: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x0019-003a in Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool$Holder;.close ()V
01-10 13:42:37.563: I/dalvikvm(506): Failed resolving Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool; interface 298 'Ljavax/management/DynamicMBean;'
01-10 13:42:37.563: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/util/SimplePool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.563: W/dalvikvm(506): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool; (146)
01-10 13:42:37.563: W/dalvikvm(506): Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;' failed
01-10 13:42:37.563: E/dalvikvm(506): Could not find class 'com.mongodb.DBPortPool', referenced from method com.mongodb.DBPortPool$Holder.get
01-10 13:42:37.563: W/dalvikvm(506): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 56 (Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;) in Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool$Holder;
01-10 13:42:37.573: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0006
01-10 13:42:37.573: D/dalvikvm(506): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0099 in Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool$Holder;.get (Lcom/mongodb/ServerAddress;)Lcom/mongodb/DBPortPool;
01-10 13:42:37.573: D/AndroidRuntime(506): Shutting down VM
01-10 13:42:37.573: W/dalvikvm(506): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mongodb.DBPortPool
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at com.mongodb.DBPortPool$Holder.get(DBPortPool.java:57)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector._set(DBTCPConnector.java:488)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.<init>(DBTCPConnector.java:44)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:272)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at breadcrumbs.java.CrumbsDb.<init>(CrumbsDb.java:21)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at breadcrumbs.java.BreadCrumbsActivity.onCreate(BreadCrumbsActivity.java:28)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-10 13:42:37.593: E/AndroidRuntime(506):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am not sure you can use a mongoDB database in an Android application, what's the stacktrace you get ?

Comment: Are you sure hostname/ip you have in app for mongoDB system is correct? Did you ping mongoDB machine from your development machine?

Comment: yes i am sure. i tested the hostname/ip using a plain java file in text edit and ran it to print out results; it worked as intended.although, i just pinged right now and received a 100% packet loss (the host machine is a 32 bit Amazon EC2 linux box).

Comment: HOLY EPIC ERRORLOG, what a dump is this only the error (red) part, or just everything?

Comment: this is my log cat actually. sorry i am not too familiar with all the jargon yet

Comment: Are you running this in the emulator?  And if so, is this a domain name that the emulator can resolve to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This driver does not support Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714921/android-mongodb-noclassdeffounderror-com-mongodb-dbportpool); there is an [open issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-291) for mongo to support it.

Comment: yea so I've been reading. the support has yet to be resolved. thanks everyone