# Offline response in android

Tags: android, offline

My Question is

Is there any free library which converts response from server to sqlite database.User should have data online/offline.

if connection was there response will be from server update db

if connection was not there response will be directly from db.

How to proceed with converting resposne to sqlite database.

Any links or sample code helps me alot

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can write a service which checks for server connection.

If connection is there then get the Json ,parse it and store it in the DB as you need

If there is no connection  then use the Db values.

You can use [This link](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/) to convert the json to dbObject.

Comment: thanks for quick reply hope link will help.Will check and update you

Comment: i had written the code which is in link but throwing illegal argument exception while creating db.please kindly let me know what will be the problem below is the code   MongoURI uri=new MongoURI(url);
                mongo = new Mongo(uri);
                db = mongo.getDB("contacst.db");
                collection = db.getCollection(TAG_CONTACTS);

Comment: try db = mongo.getDB("contacst"); instead of db = mongo.getDB("contacst.db");

Comment: its exception related creating uri not creating db can you tell how to create mongo object for this api http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

Comment: sorry i guess this mongodb wont work i guess check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808513/android-my-application-wont-run-because-i-need-to-handle-an-unknownhostexcepti

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such library exist. You should do it by yourself. 
For service you could write `isAlive()` method and for json to db. I suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563118/how-to-save-data-from-json-in-sqlite-in-android).